# Laravel migration Error no: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a ‘posts’ table and an ‘arrival’ table which references ‘flightno’ *(in text string format)* as a foreign key. However, when I run the Laravel migration I get the dreaded error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `atc`.`#sql-2350_84` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `arrival` add constraint
>   `arrival_flightno_foreign` foreign key (`flightno`) references `posts`
>   (`flightno`))
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `atc`.`#sql-2350_84` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed")

**Posts**

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('flightno');
    $table->string('flighttype');
    $table->string('toa');
    $table->string('doa');
    $table->string('runway');
    $table->string('route');
    $table->string('parking');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Arrival**

```php
Schema::create('arrival', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('flightno');
    $table->string('cleaning');
    $table->string('rampservice');
    $table->string('waste');
    $table->string('deicing');
    $table->foreign('flightno')->references('flightno')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you forgot to put indexes and set length of `flightno` columns. This should work:

**Posts**

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
    $table->string('flightno', 30)->index();
    // ...
});
```

**Arrival**

```php
Schema::create('arrival', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
    $table->string('flightno', 30)->index();
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the foreign key column use unsignedBigInteger to avoid mismatch foreign key data type problem.

For example in your arrival table use the type of flightno as unsignedBigInteger.

Posts:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('flightno');
    $table->string('flighttype');
    $table->string('toa');
    $table->string('doa');
    $table->string('runway');
    $table->string('route');
    $table->string('parking');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Arrival:

```
Schema::create('arrival', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    //---Change flightno type to unsignedBigInteger and if u faced any problem just use nullable at the end of flightno.
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('flightno');
    $table->string('cleaning');
    $table->string('rampservice');
    $table->string('waste');
    $table->string('deicing');
    $table->foreign('flightno')->references('flightno')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

It will solved the problems of a lot of people that faced this problem.